# Comparing Range Between Two Arrays

Tags: python-3.x

I have two different arrays:

```
A = [1,6,8]
B = [2,5,6,9]
```

I want to check whether there is at least one element from B exist in Range of A

Example:

Let's say I have two values `X = 1 and Y = 8` from list A.

I want to check whether there is such element in list B exist within the range of X and Y.

> The answer that I expected is for python to tell me that 2, 5, 6 are
>   elements from B that fit in the range of A[0] and A[2]

I tried:

```
for n in range(x,y)

    if n in B
```

but it didn't work.

Did I do it wrong?

Comment: To be clear, what exactly do `X` and `Y` represent? Values in `A`? So if  `X` = 1 and `Y` = 8, that means look in the full range of `A` but if `X` = 1 and `X` = 6 that would only look in the first 2 elements of A. I also assume that `A` is always sorted low to high?

Comment: @PaulRooney Yes, I basically want to know is there any element in list B that has value larger than `A[0] which is 1` but smaller than `A[2] which is 8`. In this case, I expected that it will tell me that THERE EXIST element in B which are `2,5, and 6.`

Comment: X & Y, A[0] & A[2], A = [1, 6, 8]. It's (very) unclear what exactly defines your range. A range only needs two elements, not three, nor X and Y.

Comment: Are you using integers only? Or any (floating point) value in the range defined by A (and thus any float in B)?

Comment: @PaulRooney just a confirmation either exist or not, can be with boolean or with int 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

```
list_1 = [1, 6, 8]
list_2 = [2,5,5,8]
for n in range (list_1 [0], list_1 [2]):
    if n in list_2:
        print n
```

Comment: It turns out I'm just missing to mention the array itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check whether there is at least one element from B exist in Range of A

To find whether any element from `B` exists in `A`:

```
exists = not set(A).isdisjoint(B)
```

that is `O(len(A) + len(B))` in time unlike `exists = any(b in A for b in B)` that is `O(len(A) * len(B))` algorithm e.g., if `A`, `B` have one million elements each then the first method ([`set.isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint)) requires around a million (`10**6`) operations while the second method (with the loop) requires around a million of millions (`10**12`) operations that is much too slow.

---

To find whether any element from `B` exists in `range(A[0], A[2])`:

```
exists = any(A[0] <= b < A[2] for b in B)
```